# How do you compare the user's input to values in a dictionary provided?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to compare the user's input to values in a dictionary provided.

Question:

> Your program should ask how much money you have to spend. Then, it should use the dictionary we've provided with the items and their prices to figure out which ones you have enough money for.

Code

```py
wishlist = {
    'PS5': 750,
    'Phone case': 30,
    'Oodie': 90,
    'LEGO Hogwarts Castle': 650,
    'JBL Headphones': 130,
    'Drum kit': 520,
    'Phone recharge': 30,
    'Earrings': 110,
    'Spotify subscription': 60,
    'Hockey stick': 130,
    'Big Toblerone': 16,
    'Volleyball': 90,
    'Fitbit': 99,
    'Harry Potter box set': 65,
    'New Chucks': 70,
    }

money = int(input('How much money do you have to spend? '))
print('The presents you can afford are:')
for gifts in wishlist.keys():
    print(gifts)
```

I'm trying to compare the money input with the cost of the items and output only the items that are affordable by the input amount.

For example
[image: demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired solution:

```
wishlist = {'PS5': 750, 'Phone case': 30, 'Oodie': 90, 'LEGO Hogwarts Castle': 650, 'JBL Headphones': 130, 'Drum kit': 520, 'Phone recharge': 30, 'Earrings': 110, 'Spotify subscription': 60, 'Hockey stick': 130, 'Big Toblerone': 16, 'Volleyball': 90, 'Fitbit': 99, 'Harry Potter box set': 65, 'New Chucks': 70}

money = int(input('How much money do you have to spend? '))
print('The presents you can afford are:')
for gifts in wishlist.keys():
  if wishlist.get(gifts) <= money:
    print(gifts)
```

Hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
wishlist = {'PS5': 750, 'Phone case': 30, 'Oodie': 90, 'LEGO Hogwarts Castle': 650, 'JBL Headphones': 130, 'Drum kit': 520, 'Phone recharge': 30, 'Earrings': 110, 'Spotify subscription': 60, 'Hockey stick': 130, 'Big Toblerone': 16, 'Volleyball': 90, 'Fitbit': 99, 'Harry Potter box set': 65, 'New Chucks': 70}

money = int(input('How much money do you have to spend? '))
print('The presents you can afford are:')
for (item,value) in wishlist.items():
  if value <= money:
      print(item,value)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `enumerate()`? You're not doing anything with `i`.